# Pre-requisite and Launch condition

Tags: installation, prerequisites

I am having a small problem regarding pre-requisites and launch condition for setup.

For example, my setup is having one launch condition requiring "Software1" and one prerequisite installing "Software2".

So, if a system does not have both requirements "Software1" and "Software2" on installing the setup:

1. Is it shows the prerequiste dialog for "Software2"
2. Is it shows the launch codnition for "Software1".

I am observing the behaviour that I am getting a prerequiste dialog box using my setup.

Is there any way to set the order or to show the launch condition as first dialog while installing the setup?

Comment: A language and installer technology would be nice to know.  This may change depending on these.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using InstallShield prerequisites in your installation, they will be installed by the setup.exe, not the MSI. Launch conditions are handled by the MSI, which will not be run until after the prerequisites are installed. Basically, this means that you can't show launch conditions until after prerequisites have been installed.

That being said, you may be able to configure the conditions on the prerequisites in such a way that the prerequisites would not be installed if you know in advance if a launch condition cannot be satisfied. The net effect of this is that the launch conditions are shown without installing prerequisites, but this isn't a really simple way to achieve this.

In InstallShield 2009, you can configure "feature prerequisites" that will not be installed until after features have been selected. In this case, prerequisites associated with selected features will be installed at the end of the Install UI sequence, or, if the installation is being run without a UI, just before the Install Execute sequence.

Answer (score 0):

without more detail on what sort of installer system you're using, it is going to be hard to help. Assuming you're using the built-in stuff in visual studio, look on google for *visual studio msi custom actions*. I believe one of the allowable actions is to start another executable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MSI launch conditions, you cannot tell which order launch conditions will be evaluated.

If you do need to check something in a specific order, you'll need to use a Custom Action rather than a launch condition.